# Php, Jquery - Post variable to other page with leaving the page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm working on a complex project which needs nice variable posting between pages without post or get. I made it with get, before that I used post in php, but then I started to use jquery which has got better ways to do things. I know how to pass variables between two pages without leaving the page:

```
visible    function blahblah (id){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "blahblah.php",
    data: $(id).serialize(),
    success: function(data){
    $('#results').html(data);
    }
    });
    }
```

I always show results in a div, but the one I want to achieve is different. I need to pass a variable WITH leaving the page, but without using php post or get. I did search for it, but I wasn't successful. Can you help me out in this, if it's possible? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why not use a GET/POST html form?

Comment: You can use a small `.post()` **before**  you leave the page and save to a `SESSION` variable to be retrieved later on another page.  You could also use a small `.post()` **before** you leave the page and save said variables in a database to be retrieved later.  --

Comment: get/post is about the ONLY way you can pass data between pages, unless you care to mess around with setting/reading cookies in javascript.

Comment: You could use localStorage [localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

Comment: In order to understand your objective we need to know why a GET/POST form is no solution. Do you need to send data to the server, or only maintain it between pages on the browser?

Comment: The reason why I can't use post or get, because I don't want to lose the go back browser function and I don't want to show the variable content in get to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're worried about losing the "go back" function I assume this is because of the annoying warning that appears when you go back to a page that has posted data? To get around that you can try (as others have stated):

1. POST your form normally to the page
2. Save variables in $_SESSION[]

   $_SESSION['var1'] = $_POST['var1'];
3. Change the header to refresh the page:

   header('Location: ' . $_SEVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
   exit;

That way no one sees what you've posted by GET and you avoid the annoying "Resubmit your posted variables" message.

Comment: It's the best way to do this. Thank you and for the others again.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if I got your question perfectly right..I think you want to:

1. Send your data to a page using POST/GET
2. Redirect to another page. Use header function for this.

But, when you say, you don't want to use POST/GET, I really get confused! How can you communicate with your server then? Setting everything to session, can never be a good solution.

Comment: I don't want to lose the go back browser function but I don't want to show the variable content to the user within get. I think sessions aren't the best way, but if it's not solvable with ajax/jquery, then I think it's the only way for me.